# How to load properties file in Mule ESB 3.9.0 as per the environment?

Tags: mule-esb

I am working on Mule ESB version 3.9.0 Community Edition.
I have to deploy the esb application to different environments like dev,int,prod etc. So I did the following:

```
mule-app.properties:
env = dev
```

And have created three properties files:

```
esb-frontoffice-dev.config.properties
esb-frontoffice-int.config.properties
esb-frontoffice-prod.config.properties
```

Now in the ESB Configuration file, I have defined the property-placeholder as follows:

```
  <context:property-placeholder location="esb-frontoffice-${env}.config.properties"/>
```

Then after the artifact is built, I am deploying it in the Mule ESB 3.9.0 runtime server. But I am getting the below error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [esb-frontoffice-${env}.config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:150) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:80) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define env as a Java property in MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf.

Example:

```
wrapper.java.additional.23=-Denv=prod
```

Instead of 23 use any number not used previously in the file for other properties.

Comment: Thank you @aled   This solution worked perfectly. However I will like to understand this: the mule-app.properties did not work when i was deploying the application on server but it worked when i was doing dev and run the flow in the Anypoint Studio. why is this happening?

Comment: mule-app.properties is packaged with the application and can not be changed per environment. It is good enough for testing in Studio. Setting the Java property is per Mule server.